# Cannot replace command 'webpack' by 'npm run build'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

Pls someone explain this to me.
I want to use the command npm run build to call webpack. So I modify the script in file package.json. But it did not work. I am using linux

This is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "learn-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learn Webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is the error, it already installed cli but it keep send this message

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! learn-webpack@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the learn-webpack@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
         There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/huong/.npm/_logs/2018-03-27T14_09_22_103Z-debug.log
```

Comment: it is very clear you need to install `webpacl-cli`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the instructions

> `The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.`
>
> `Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.`
>
> `-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D`

Just run:

```
npm install webpack-cli -D -g
```

`-g` for good measure, then try running build again and it should work :)

Comment: is -g for global?

Comment: Installing it globally without specifying it as a devDep will break it for anyone else that hasn't installed it globally. I suggest you add it to you devDeps and avoid installing it globally

Comment: -D and -g should do both, no? What is the harm in running -g as well as -D? Just curious as I've never experienced issues doing this.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't install webpack-cli into your devDependencies

```
npm install webpack-cli -D
```

Actually should solve your problem

Maybe you installed webpack-cli globally, but it's not in your devDependencies

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling a function directly like

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

Webpack is searched as a command from your $PATH. 
Using `npm install webpack-cli -D` installs it not globally under a $PATH but locally under `./node_modules`.

Therefore you have 2 choices:

- Installing it globally (-g): `npm -g i webpack-cli`
- Running it from the node_module directory: `node_modules/<path to webpack>`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed webpack into your project instead of globally, try this:

```
"build": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack"
```